Issue with Custom Chain Configuration in Hardhat: Network Not Appearing
I'm trying to add the LineaSepolia network as a custom chain in my Hardhat project. I've configured it in my hardhat.config.js as follows:
{
  network: "lineaSepolia",
  chainId: 59141,
  urls: {
    apiURL: "https://api-sepolia.lineascan.build/",
    browserURL: "https://sepolia.lineascan.build/",
  },
}

However, when I run the command npx hardhat verify --list-networks, the LineaSepolia network doesn't appear in the list. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the custom network configuration is recognized by Hardhat?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried adding a custom network configuration for LineaSepolia in my Hardhat project. And the code snippet I used in my hardhat.config.js
